# How to identify which line in the batch file has a syntax error?

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax-error

I'm running a batch file on Windows and got this error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Is that possible to identify which line in the batch file is incorrect ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please remove @echo off, and run from a command line. Still on your 7-zip problem?